# Router reports different MAC address than iwconfig

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, opensuse, mac-address

The address returned by iwconfig is nearly the same - the first number is off by 2 and the last by 1. Does anyone know why I'm getting a different result depending on where I look? I happen to know the address I get directly from the router is the original one and the one I get from iwconfig is the one that changed.

If it helps at all, I have a Netgear WNDR3400v3 and I'm running Opensuse 13.1

There is a possibly separate issue that cropped up recently that I haven't looked too deeply into in the interests of "If it ain't broke, don't fix it." My laptop (all other devices work fine) is unable to connect to my personal wifi network when the guest network isn't being broadcast.

Comment: What do you mean "directly from the router"?

Comment: I mean that's the address I see when I look it up in the router's admin dashboard.